# Problems starting Postgresql with sudo

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-17.10

Running Ubuntu 17.10 and I am having an issue running Postgres. It was working a couple weeks ago, but now I have this problem.

```
sudo su postgres psql

/usr/bin/psql: line 19: use: command not found
/usr/bin/psql: line 20: use: command not found
/usr/bin/psql: line 21: use: command not found
/usr/bin/psql: line 22: use: command not found
/usr/bin/psql: psql: line 24: syntax error near unexpected token `$version,'
/usr/bin/psql: psql: line 24: `my ($version, $cluster);'
```

I have no idea what to do, the syntax looks normal.

Comment: Is `/usr/bin/psql` a Perl script that starts with `#!/bin/sh` or similar? Line 24 suggests that it is Perl, line 19 suggests that it is Perl being fed to a shell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

instead.

I actually do not know what your command does. A quick look to `man su` does not really clarify what `su` will do with extra arguments but obviously it is not *starting* `psql`, it is probably feeding the file contents to the shell.

Comment: Thank you for your help and this is correct. I was using the other way because I had seen someone else using it to start postgres and I figured it was the correct way. (Bad assumption)

Comment: sudo without the "-u" or plain "-" inherits your current environment.  With the "-" it sets up a new environment as if you were logging in as the other user.